# How to send the request from react native to express js?

Tags: react-native, express

I have concern right now regarding sending the request body from my react native to the back end express JS. Once the button press or click, the logs from my server shows undefined. All get methods are working, except the post method. I read a lot of documents regarding on that.

1. https://dev.to/saulojoab/how-to-get-data-from-an-mysql-database-in-react-native-53a4
2. https://reactnativecode.com/fetch-api-tutorial-insert-into-mysql-php/

**Imported module:**

```
const express = require('express');
var cors = require('cors')
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const mysql = require('mysql');
const app = express();

app.use(express.json());

app.use(express.urlencoded({
  extended: true
}));


var cors = require('cors');

app.use(cors());
```

**Post Method:**

```
app.post('/api/new_readings/', function (req, res) {

  connection.getConnection(function (err, connection) {

    console.log(req.body.name);

   
  });
});
```

**Submit Handler:**

```
 fetch('http://myippppp:3000/api/new_readings/', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: 
            {
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            },
        body: { 
          "name": "x",
          "email": "a",
          "password": "1234"
        }
      })
      .then(response => response.json()) 
      .then(serverResponse => console.warn(serverResponse))
```

**Error:**

[image: Error]

Hope someone help on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct syntax is

Client side

```
fetch('http://myippppp:3000/api/new_readings/', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: 
            {
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            },
        body: JSON.stringify({ 
          "name": "x",
          "email": "a",
          "password": "1234"
        }) // need to use JSON.stringify
      })
      .then(response => response.json()) 
      .then(serverResponse => console.warn(serverResponse))
```

Server Side

```
app.post('/api/new_readings/', function (req, res) {

    console.log(req.body.name);

    return res.json({ ok: true });
});
```